# Intuitive reasoning why the integral of dv is velocity?

Tags: calculus, integration, physics, intuition, kinematics

I'm struggling to understand the geometrical/physical meaning behind why $\int_{v_0}^{v_f} dv=v$, especially how this relates to the area under the curve.

I was recently looking at the following simple derivation of kinematics equations and got stuck on step 3:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dv_x}{dt}=a_x \tag{1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\int_{v_0}^{v_1}dv_x=\int_{t_0}^{t_1} a_x \, dt \tag{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
v_x(t_1)-v_x(t_0)=\int_{t_0}^{t_f} a_x \, dt \tag{3}
\end{equation}

I understand the mathematical reason (it is equivalent to $\int 1 \,dv$ and consequently, the antiderivative is $v$) and a reason having to do with adding up an infinite number of small velocity differences ($dv$) that add to the total velocity, but am struggling to make the connection between the area under the function $f(v)=1$ and velocity itself?

[Pictures of area under the graphs (representing the two integrals)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqZXC.png)

In other words, I get how the area under the curve of the $a_x(t)$ graph represents velocity (you are multiplying $a_x$ by a small difference in time, which will yield velocity if you add it up), but how do we use this same logic to reason why the area under $f(y)=1$ (what does this function even represent?) results in our velocity?

Hopefully this wasn't too confusing and I am more than willing to provide extra clarification. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're running into the issue that area under the curve is not the most natural representation of integration, but an artifact of how we sometimes can choose to represent functions as graphs living in higher dimensional spaces. Instead it is better to think of integration as collecting small densities on a set to get a total mass.

Comment: The total is the sum of its parts. The $dv$s are the small changes in the velocity so when you sum them starting from an initial velocity you get the total change in velocity.